# Add text to end of all lines in string

Tags: python

Say I have this string:

```
""" 
iris
jonah
car
donut
"""
```

How do I add something at the end of all the lines? The amount of lines in the string may vary from time to time.

Something like:

```
l = duplicate.split('\n')
l[1]+= 'X'
l = '\n'.join(l)
print(l)
```

Duplicate being the string's name.

This code only adds 'X' to the end of line 1.

How can I do this for every line?

Desired output:

```
""" 
irisX
jonahX
carX
donutX
"""
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you telling some like [this](https://regex101.com/r/ys08Jt/1)?

Comment: @Peri461 Can you point out the reference that states that triple quote strings should not be used for anything else than docstrings?

Comment: @Peri461 Citation needed.

Comment: @Peri461 that's just personal taste. triplequotes are very useful when you paste a template of an existing file in your code, or just for that [mcve] (the real input probably comes from a file)

Comment: Ah yeah, I just found some stuff elsewhere too. I had the wrong idea about using triple quotes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, split as you did `duplicate` on `'\n'`:

```
splitted = duplicate.split('\n')
```

Then append `'x'` at the end of each line with a `for`, and join these line on `'\n'`.
I do both operations in a signle line:

```
"\n".join(line + "x" for line in splitted)
```

If you're not familiar with generator expressions, this is somewhat similar to:

```
withSuffixes = []
for line in l:
    withSuffixes.append(splitted + "x")
"\n".join(withSuffixes)
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
addition = 'X'
new_string = duplicate.replace('\n', addition + '\n')
```

Comment: The only answer so far which brings up the `replace` function in strings.

Comment: This works, kind of, the last line doesn't get an 'x'. :/ But thanks!

Comment: In that case add it manually! Good out of the box thinking for this answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `l[1]+= 'X'` line and change `l = '\n'.join(l)` into `l = 'X\n'.join(l)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to apply a function to all elements of the list you obtained using `split` and then `join` the elements in a single string:

```
"\n".join(map(lambda word: word+"x", s.split("\n")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, uses list comprehension to add 'X' to each line and then joins it by a newline character.

```
duplicate = """ 
iris
jonah
car
donut
"""

l = duplicate.split('\n')
l = [line + 'X' for line in l]
final = '\n'.join(l)
```